# Error, in moving files, due to destination directory not being empty

Tags: java, oop, directory, move, target

The code below is a component of a much larger script. I have removed the unnecessary parts to just expose this essential, error causing part.
The problem here is very simple but frustrating. I want to move file from 'Directory A' to 'Directory B'. If for any reason, 'Directory B' is not COMPLETELY EMPTY....the code WILL fail.

Essentially the code works ONE time, because at the first run, the destination directory will be empty. When I change the target directory, to perform the second run, the destination directory already has files in there....and so the code fails.
how can I stop this failure? I need to be able to dump files into the same destination directory, continuously...

```
package hi;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;




public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {



                try {
                    Files.move(new File("C://DL//New Folder//JAN- 
 2019//").toPath(), new File("C://DL2//New Folder").toPath(), 
  StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            } 


        }
```

Comment: You say you change the target directory but then at the end you're asking for the same target directory... which is it?

Comment: Please add the full Stack Trace to your question.

Comment: Oh my bad @gfos, I've just edited it . I need to dump into the same destination directory continuously

Comment: When the destination folder is not empty, this is the error I would get...

java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException: C:\DL2\New Folder
 at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.move(Unknown Source)
 at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.move(Unknown Source)
 at java.nio.file.Files.move(Unknown Source)
 at hi.Main.main(Main.java:20)